# WSO2 BPS Wait Activity waits longer than what is configured

Tags: wso2, wso2-business-process

I´ve noticed that some wait activities in my BPEL processes are waiting more than the time that they are configured to.

[image]

This particular activity is setup to wait 5 seconds but it actually waited 41 seconds.

I tried searching for a bug abou this but couldn't find anything.

I need to understand why this is happening and how to fix. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because there were fewer scheduler threads available than the number of running processes, therefore there were not enough scheduler threads to pick and resume pending instances.

The fix was to increase ODE schedules threads in ODESchedulerThreadPoolSize parameter.